# disringuish a List from an integer Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can we distinguish a list from an integer in Haskell?
In the other words I need a function which returns True for 3 and returns false for [3]
Thank You

Comment: Haskell makes it very hard for you not to know whether you have a list or an integer. It's easy to write code that only works for one of these; the compiler will then not allow this code to run on the wrong input. Why would you want to run the same function on both anyway?

Comment: You really need to explain why you do not know what type of argument you will have.  Everything in Haskell has a type, whether or not you give it a type signature, and if you apply a function to the wrong type the compiler will raise a type error at compile time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is pointless because you usually know what type a value is, and if not, you will have a hard time figuring out what to do with it. However, it *might* be of use in, say, TemplateHaskell or elsewhere, so...

```
class IsAList a where
    isAList :: a -> Bool

instance IsAList Int where
    isAList = const False

instance IsAList [a] where
    isAList = const True
```

Now `isAList [2] = True` and `isAList (2 :: Int) = False`. Please note that `isAList "asdf" = True` because a string is a list of characters.

If you can perhaps elaborate *why* do you need this?..

Answer (score 13):

Use a sum datatype such as `Either`

```
f :: Either Int [a] -> Bool
f (Left _)  = True
f (Right _) = False

f (Left 3)    -- evaluates to True
f (Right [3]) -- evaluates to False
f (Left 4)    -- also evaluates to True, if you want to check for certain values 
              -- within each type you should handle them explicitly
```